# Is it possible to have only one notification for a text message until the message is read?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

I've been looking for a while but I cannot find out if I can limit it so that I only receive the first notification and no others until I've read the message.

There is a notification setting that will prevent the same text message from generating a follow up notification after a period of time (default is 2 minutes I believe).

I'm looking for a solution for Person A sends me 4 texts in the span of a minute. I'd like to not get a notification for messages 2 through 4 unless I've read 1.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be Settings -> Notifications -> Messages -> Repeat Alerts -> Never?

Comment: I wish! That's for the 2 minute follow up on the same text message. I'll update the question to be clearer.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it wasn't clear from your original question that you wanted to avoid notifications for further messages from the same user. I don't think such a setting exists.

Comment: Sorry about that :/. Yeah I don't think there is anything either as I haven't found anything through Google myself.

Comment: There's a setting for this? Fantastic! (: